# Why is my code returning " [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]"?

Tags: javascript, loops, undefined

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  let lum = [];
  for (let i = arr[1]; i > arr[0]; i--) {
    lum.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return lum;
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
```

I want my code to do 4-3, then add the result to `lum` and so on until it reaches 1 but i'm stuck at this point. I don't know why it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `i` is not an index in your loop; `i` is an element.

Answer (score 3):

You're pushing `arr[i]` onto the result:

```
lum.push(arr[i]);
```

So for example when `i` is 4 (because `arr[1]` is 4), what is the value `arr[4]` that you're pushing to the result?  It's `undefined` in the array provided.  I suspect you meant to just push `i` to the result?:

```
lum.push(i);
```

For example:

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  let lum = [];
  for (let i = arr[1]; i > arr[0]; i--) {
    lum.push(i);
  }
  return lum;
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
```

Comment: Should the result also include `1`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Maybe?  Though based on the name `sumAll` I'd expect the result to just be a sum of values.  The OP would have to clarify the logic of whatever this operation is meant to do.  But what it was doing (the `undefined` results) was at least because the original code was referencing undefined array elements.